How to make the window size to constantly shrink in pygame?
I'm making a game in pygame and for one of the levels in my game, the window would shrink constantly, forcing the player to move fast before they couldn't see the screen anymore but I don't know how to do that exactly.
Here's basically what I tried to make the window shrink:
import pygame
import sys

size_change = 0.8
X = 1600
Y = 900

background_color = (255, 255, 255)

running = True

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while running:
    DISPLAY = pygame.display.set_mode([X * size_change, Y * size_change])

    DISPLAY.fill(background_color)

    size_change -= 0.0005

    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(60)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

The DISPLAY would keep updating the window to change the size of the X and Y and it does work. However, the problem is that the window gets a weird flickering effect while it's shrinking and it sometimes breaks the window size entirely. Is there a different way?

That's precisely how I would have done it (thanks for saving me from finding out the hard way). I would suggest not resizing the display, and instead resizing a surface that gets blitted onto the display. That's an interesting resizing function, btw (i.e., I'm not sure, off the top of my head, how to compute its convergence... which I would probably want to do in your scenario, since the screen size should be <=1 after some number of steps).

As per my comment, I'd suggest not resizing the entire display. I don't think it's able to buffer properly. I'd also see about a termination condition.
#! /usr/bin/env python

import pygame
import sys

size_change = 0.8
X = 1600
Y = 900

background_color = (255, 255, 255)

running = True

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

surface = pygame.Surface((X, Y)) # Create a surface with the initial size
    
DISPLAY = pygame.display.set_mode((X, Y))  # Set the display size

while running:
    # Resize the surface
    new_width = int(X * size_change)
    new_height = int(Y * size_change)
    if (new_width < 1) or (new_height < 1):
        print('I just lost the game')
        running = False
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()
    resized_surface = pygame.transform.scale(surface, (new_width, new_height))

    DISPLAY.fill(background_color)

    surface_x = (X - new_width) // 2
    surface_y = (Y - new_height) // 2

    #DISPLAY.blit(resized_surface, (0, 0)) # Blit the resized surface onto the display
    DISPLAY.blit(resized_surface, (surface_x, surface_y)) # Blit the resized surface onto the centered position on the display

    size_change -= 0.0005 # srsly this looks wild

    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(60) # fps

    for event in pygame.event.get(): # graceful termination
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

__author__    : str           = "AI Assistant"
__maintainer__: str           = "@lmaddox"


To resize the display you can just call the pygame.display.set_mode() to resize it to a smaller size although this may be buggy, another way to do so is to blit the graphics onto a second surface then bliting it onto the window,
This method will be less buggy.
window2 = pygame.Surface((windowWidth, WindowHeight))
...
window2.blit(graphic)
...
window.blit(window2, (0, 0))
...
window2 = pygame.transform.scale(window2, required size)

